# moongose nested subdocument update and delete

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nested, mongoose-schema, subdocument

```
"_id": {
    "$oid": "577cc50d10b5a6c42b26f414"
}, 
"firstName": "new",
"lastName": "new", 
"__v": 0,
"A": [
    {
        "AfirstName": "AfirstName",
        "AlastName": "AlastName", 
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "577dbef2f2c9f5901f402efe"
        },
        "AB": [
            {
                "AB1firstName": "AB1firstName",
                "AB1lastName": "AB1lastName", 
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "577dd3b1495663ec2a6ca456"
                }
            },
            {
                "AB2firstName": "AB2firstName",
                "AB2lastName": "AB2lastName", 
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "577dd3bc495663ec2a6ca45a"
                }
            }
        ]
    }

] 
  Example.update({  _id: ,  A._id: , A.AB._id: }  ,
{"$set": {"A.$.AB": data}},
function(err,model){ console.log(model); if (err) throw err;  })
```

This will just update the first data of AB i want to update data of AB sub-doc by _id and also want to remove the particular nested sub-doc with _id

Answer (score 2):

```
 Example.findById(_id,function(err,doc){
                            var result = doc.A.id(AId).AB.id(AB.ABId);
                            result.AB1firstName="first Name";
                            result.AB1lastName=  "Last Name"; 
                            doc.save(); 
                         });
```

This will update

Answer (score 0):

Each document has an _id. DocumentArrays have a special id method for looking up a document by its _id.

```
Example.findOne({  _id: id,  A._id: Aid, A.AB._id:  ABid},
            function(err,model){ 
             if (err) throw err;
             var ABDoc  model.A.id(Aid).AB.id(ABid);
              ABDoc.AB2firstName="new value";
              ABDoc.AB2lastName="new value";
               model.save();
        })
```